# How do I pull a CSV file into R and keep my names and labels?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to pull in a CSV file exported from Qualtrics. When I read in my file, it captures the variable name (first row) but my labels are in row 2. How do I read in row 2 as a label and not as my first data line?

I tried this :

```
filename<-read.csv("filename.csv", header = true)
varNames<-read.csv(t1, nrows=1, stringsAsFactors= FALSE, header=FALSE)
varLabels<-read.csv(t1, nrows=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

but I keep getting an error like this:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
'file' must be a character string or connection
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: ```?read.csv``` shows there is a ```skip``` function. So it might be as simple as skipping the first row with ```skip = 1```, then it should make the next row the labels. Your error though indicates the filename isn't correct, so I'm not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: The filename should be in quotations if it is the name of the file. Without quotations it is assumed to be a variable name whose value is the file name. For grabbing the variable labels, `readLines()` might be useful.